# Plot every column in a line plot (R)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe where columns are different dates (for our purposes we'll use different days) and rows are different states.

```
    M   Tu  W   Th  F   Sa  Su
AL. 5   2   6   0   10  10  3   
KY. 1   2   2   10  1   0   8   
MH. 9   0   0   8   7   9   10  
NH. 10  9   5   6   7   9   0
```

I am trying to plot every date on the x-axis and every value with the appropriate date on the Y-axis. They'll be specified by color depending on state in the legend.

I have attempted to use native plotting functions and ggplot to no avail as I can only successfully plot by state on the x-axis and not the dates as the x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `matplot`

```
matplot(t(df1), type = 'l', col = seq_len(nrow(df1)), xaxt = "n")
legend("top", row.names(df1), col = seq_len(nrow(df1)), fill = seq_len(nrow(df1)))
axis(1, at = seq_along(df1), labels = colnames(df1))
```

Comment: Let's say I had a list of states I wanted to select for specifically in the plot and only graph those states:

swing = c("MH", "NH")
swing.index = which(rownames(df1) %in% swing)

How would I only plot those states?

Comment: @user1713336  Then subset the dataset for those states before doing the plot.  Not sure if it is column or row names.  `dfN <- dfN[yourvectorofstates,]` assuming that states are the row names

Comment: The only issue I have now is that the x-axis values are the numbers 0 to 100 rather than the dates. Thank you for the help

Comment: @user1713336  As I showed in the plot, use the `xaxt = "n"` and then with `axis` change the `labels`